# Can't make successful call via remote JSON RPC

Tags: bitcoind

[image]

I can verify that my node is up and that the port is up via the above method, however no amount of effort has allowed me to successfully make a remote RPC call.

I am booting my node via `$ bitcoind -daemon`

I can make RPC calls via the same server without an issue using `$ bitcoin-cli getinfo`

My `bitcoin.conf` file looks like:

`rpcuser=rpcuser
rpcpassword=anthony
rpcallowip=::/0`

I have also tried:

`rpcuser=notmyrealuser
rpcpassword=notmyrealpass
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/`

Without luck, both of which were suggested here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/4894 by the lead Bitcoin engineer.

I am trying to authenticate using curl, the two scripts I am using are:

`curl --user notmyrealuser --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }'  -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://124.223.81.11:8333/`

and also:
`curl --data-binary 
'{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://notmyrealuser:notmyrealpass@104.223.81.11:8333/`

Nothing is working so I figured I would ask here after several hours of not making progress, everytime I receive:

`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to send RPC queries to the P2P network port. You should use port 8332 instead of 8333.

Bitcoin Core:

- interacts with other Bitcoin nodes on the network using the P2P protcol via port 8333 (or whatever you configure `-port` to be)
- responds to RPC queries (JSON-RPC) via port 8332 (or whatever you configure `-rpcport` to be).

Comment: And just like that it's working. :) Infinite thanks man!

Comment: I have the same issue. it's still "connection refused" for me even though i use 8332. but works locally when i execute on my cloud instance as 127.0.0.1:8332

any other things to check ?

Comment: i get a different error on 8333: "RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response"